# The product of $2×653×733×977$ has each digit exactly once except for one, which one is it?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The product of $2×653×733×977$ is a number with nine digits and it contains every digit once except for one, which digit is that?

I noticed that it is a product of primes, but so far I cannot solve it without multiplying it out. I suspect I can solve this using modular arithmetic but I have no idea how. Any help?

Comment: seven... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+2%C3%97653%C3%97733%C3%97977

Comment: Hint: Do it mod $9$

Comment: @janmarqz Do you really think that is helpful? Anybody can use a calculator.

Comment: "Do you really think that is helpful? Anybody can use a calculator"  Well, sure.  But tell them not to.  It's a puzzle and a challenge to was mathematical reasoning.  You can always use a calculator to check yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the number $\bmod 9$

Full solution:

> $\bmod 9$ the number is $2$, if we had each digit once the number would be $0\bmod 9$. If the missing digit is $x$ we have $0-x\equiv 2\bmod 9\implies x+2\equiv 0\bmod 9\implies x\equiv -2\equiv 7\bmod 9$ so the digit is $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The number is $2\pmod 9$. Which digit is missing?

Answer (score 1):

In mod 9 we have

`2*653*733*977 = 2*5*4*5 = 2 mod 9`

Now we make the following table :

`0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+() = 36 = 0 mod 9`

`0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+()+9 = 37 = 1 mod 9`

`0+1+2+3+4+5+6+()+8+9 = 38 = ...`

`0+1+2+3+4+5+()+7+8+9 = 39 = ...`

`0+1+2+3+4+()+6+7+8+9 = 40 = ...`

`0+1+2+3+()+5+6+7+8+9 = 41 = ...`

`0+1+2+()+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 42 = ...`

`0+1+()+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 43 = ...`

`0+()+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 44 = ...`

`()+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45 = ...`

After that, the missing number is .....